# Rails methods vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

What are the Rails methods that are vulnerable to SQL injection, and in what form?

For example, I know that `where` with a string argument is vulnerable:

```
Model.where("name = #{params[:name]}") # unsafe
```

But a parameterized string or hash is not:

```
Model.where("name = ?", params[:name]) # safe
Model.where(name: params[:name]) # safe
```

I'm mostly wondering about `where`, `order`, `limit` and `joins`, but would like to know about any other methods that might be attack vectors.

Comment: I know that pure postings of links are not welcomed. But in this case it's faster than any other answer: [Google search with rails sql injection - first result](http://rails-sqli.org/)

Comment: Whenever you mix SQL fragments and user data, you may be vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: I think it is the same for all methods as in the example you provided for where. And although you are vulnerable if you don't use `?` there is a limit to the vulnerability. Rails limits the number of SQL operations performed to 1. So users can't end your select with a `;` and write a completely new statement.

Answer (score 4):

In Rails, `where`, `order`, `limit` and `joins` all have vulnerable forms. However, Rails limits the number of SQL operations performed to 1 so vulnerability is limited. An attacker cannot end a statement and execute a new arbitrary one.

**Where**

Where has one vulnerable form: string.

```
# string, unsafe
Model.where("name = '#{params[:name]}'")

# hash/parameterized string/array, safe
Model.where(name: params[:name])
Model.where("name = ?", params[:name])
Model.where(["name = ?", params[:name]])
```

**Order**

String form is vulnerable:

```
# unsafe
params[:order] = "1; --\n drop table users;\n --"
Model.order("#{params[:order]} ASC")

# safe
order_clause = sanitize(params[:order])
Model.order(order_clause)
```

**Limit**

Limit has no vulnerable forms, since Rails casts input to Integer beforehand.

```
Model.limit("1; -- \n SELECT password from users; -- ")
=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1; -- \n SELECT password from users; -- "
```

**Joins**

String form is vulnerable:

```
params[:table] = "WHERE false <> $1; --"
Model.where(:user_id => 1).joins(params[:table])
=> SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE false <> $1 -- WHERE "models"."user_id" = $1 [["user_id", 1]]
```

Much more comprehensive information can be found at [rails-sqli.org](http://rails-sqli.org).

Answer (score 2):

Generally: If you let the user input and save any text into your database, without escaping code, it could harm your system. Especially if these texts may contain tags/code snippets.

Comment: I agree, rather look at specific methods, do understand the inputs. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection too